# Image for Iphone 4 and Iphone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My app can have many `images` for `background`. This `images` I need download, so I don't want download separately for **iPhone 4** and **iPhone 5**. I use method `self.view.backgroundcolor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imagenamed:@"myImage.jpg"]]`. I want download one `image` for **iPhone 5** and then cut top and bottom borders for use with **iPhone 4**. How can I do it programmatically with the best way. Oh maybe there are the best solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop image using this function define the rect you want as image remaining will be removed
for this you need `CoreGraphics.framework`, so dont forget to add in your Project.

```
- (UIImage *)imageByCroppingtoRect:(CGRect)rect fromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)oldImage {
    CGSize imageSize = oldImage.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake( imageSize.width,imageSize.height - 100),NO,0.); // this height you want to change
    [oldImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake( 0, -46) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.];// from top to change X is never change
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return croppedImage;
}
```